# Selenium webdriver unable to click element while a dropdown list is in the process of opening

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

In my script I am clicking a button which opens the dropdown list, then am waiting for an element in that dropdown list to become clickable and click it. However, the dropdown list contents don't show up instantly when clicking it. Instead it's a dropdown list that gradually opens.

dropdown list EC:

```
    def wait_and_scroll_to_element(self, locator, timeout=None):
    timeout = timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout
    try:
        element= WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    except  TimeoutException:
        raise (f"presence of element: {locator} was not detected after a timeout of: {timeout} ")

    return element
```

Element in dropdown EC:

```
wait_and_scroll_to_element

def wait_and_click(self, locator, timeout=None):
    timeout = timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        raise (f"Element: {locator} not displayed with after timeout of {timeout} ")code
```

I am getting an ElementClickInterceptedException. If I put a time.sleep() between the scroll and click functions it does work. But I want to avoid using sleep if possible.

I am using python

Error message: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (461, 1181)`

Comment: Edit your question and post the full error message, properly formatted. In that exception message it should tell you which element is blocking. Find that element and deal with it... close the popup dialog, wait for a transient toast message to disappear, scroll the page away from a floating header or other UI elements, etc.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (461, 1181)

This is my error. However it's not always the same coordinates. Sometimes it even succeeds so i'm not sure what is causing this

Comment: I think i found the problem. While the dropdown list is opening, the element i want to click on is sometimes unclickable. Is there a way to wait for the dropdown list to open without using a "time.sleep()"?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that an element is blocking the dropdown element you are trying to click, causing the ElementClickInterceptedException to occur. This can happen if there is another UI element on top of the dropdown element that is intercepting the click. Since the code is running quickly, it can be difficult to identify the element causing the issue.

To resolve this issue, you can try to identify the element that is blocking the dropdown element in the HTML of the page. Once you have identified the element, you can use the WebDriverWait method with an appropriate ExpectedCondition to wait for the element to become invisible before attempting the click.

Another options would be trying a Javascript click on the dropdown element.
JavaScript command uses the click() method to trigger a click event on the element which triggers the element's default behaviour

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```